# Error de Instalación [Py3o Report Engine] Odoo 10.0

Tags: odoo

Acabo de instalar estos requerimientos de este modulo[Py3o Report Engine] :

LibreOffice.

Module :

- report

Python :

- pip install py3o.template
- pip install py3o.formats

Cuando le doy a instalar me sale este error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 362, in create
    return super(View, self).create(self._compute_defaults(values))
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/addons-extra/base_phone/models/base.py", line 31, in create
    return super(Base, self).create(vals)
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 3855, in create
    self._fields[key].determine_inverse(record)
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/fields.py", line 1046, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 220, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 380, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/addons-extra/base_phone/models/base.py", line 22, in write
    return super(Base, self).write(vals)
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 3568, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 3732, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/var/odoo/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 1081, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
ParseError: "Error mientras se validaban las restricciones


global name 'Formats' is not defined

None" while parsing /var/odoo/odoo10/addons-extra/report_py3o/views/ir_report.xml:6, near
<record id="py3o_report_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">py3o_report_view</field>
        <field name="model">ir.actions.report.xml</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.act_report_xml_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//page[@name='security']" position="before">
                <page string="LibreOffice Template" name="py3o_tab" attrs="{'invisible': [('report_type', '!=', 'py3o')]}">

                    <group name="py3o_params">
                        <field name="py3o_filetype"/>
                        <field name="py3o_multi_in_one"/>
                        <field name="py3o_template_id"/>
                        <field name="module"/>
                        <field name="py3o_template_fallback"/>
                    </group>

                </page>
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```

He intentado de todo pero estoy muy perdido en esto, soy nuevo en OpenERP. El en log del servidor no me aparece ningún error.

Gracias!!!!

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución.

Entrar al modulo Py3o Report Engine --> views y abrimos el archivo ir_report.xml
a continuación introducimos las dos líneas de abajo :

**from openerp import tools**

**from openerp.tools.translate import _**

Así quedaría :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <!-- Inherit from base.act_report_xml_view to add py3o-related settings. -->

    <record id="py3o_report_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <strong>from openerp import tools</strong>
        <strong>from openerp.tools.translate import _</strong>
        <field name="name">py3o_report_view</field>
        <field name="model">ir.actions.report.xml</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.act_report_xml_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
```